# read file and store contents in a register

Tags: vim

Is there a way in vim to read a file, like with `:r`, and then store it in some register? and is there a way to do the same, but only with the lines in the file that matches some pattern?

Comment: Answers can be of a better quality when you tell us what you intend to achieve, not just ask about a technical detail out of context.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using external grep, you could do:

```
:let @x = system('grep pattern filename')
```

to place only the lines matching `pattern` from file `filename` in register `x`.

Answer (score 16):

Try this:

```
:let @x = join(readfile("~/.vimrc"), "\n")
```

It will read `.vimrc` to register `x`.

Comment: Thanks!  I was able to use your answer, but modified it somewhat.  I wanted to copy the contents of compiled version of the current sass file.  I did something like this:  `:let @+ = join(readfile(join([expand('%:t'), '.css'], "")), "\n")`

Comment: I'm using Windows and I have to use `readfile(expand("~/_vimrc"))` instead of `readfile("~/_vimrc")` because the function doesn't seem to expand `~` by itself.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a new buffer with `:new`, read the file `:r <filename>`, yank the entire file for a register (say, x) with `gg"xyG"`, and delete the buffer with `:q!`.
If you intend to perform this actions several times you can create a mapping for it.

To do the same with lines that matches a pattern, you can peform a global command (`:h :g`) before performing the copy to the register.